# How do I enable scaling or zooming on site with fixed elements?

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, mobile-safari, scaling

I've set my maximum-scale value to 1.0 in my viewport meta tag to prevent zooming, only because I have a fixed header that stays at the top if the page. Enabling scaling causes the whole layout to break when the user zooms in on touch enabled devices. I would prefer to allow scaling. What's the best way to deal with this issue?

I considered using JavaScript to detect when the page is scaled and then applying a class to the body that would allow me to override fixed elements with something more "zoom friendly." Any ideas?